# Which voltage to replace a battery?

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-divider, battery-operated

I have a little drone project that use among others thing two camera,these two camera use a battery Olympus LI-100B (Li-ion battery 3.6V 1350mAh ). On the drone the source of power will be a 3s 5200 mAh 11.4 V, i also will have a voltage converter to 5V, So should i just step down from the 5v to 3.6 and power the camera with it or there more in the story ?

Comment: I'd assume the Olympus battery would power a camera for several hours, but the flight time of your drone might likely be less than an hour. Why carry excessive battery weight if you can avoid it? You might consider sizing a 1S 3.7 V battery to give you just about the same camera time as your flight time, You might get by with only 500-800 mAh for both cameras and allocate more weight to your drive battery.

Comment: Please format the question as an electrical design question.

Comment: Hi,thanks. Actually there is two camera ( same olympus), a RTK-GPS, a intel edisson, and an autopilot to power that why i got a larger battery ( the drone have a 2.2 A battery originally ) and i try to power everything from the battery rather than having to manage couple little battery.

Answer (score 1):

A 1s 1350 mAh Lion cell provides ~= 5 Wh of energy.
A 3S 5200 mAh battery gives ~= 55 Wh.
So the small battery is about 10% of the capacity of the large one and probably runs the camera for longer than the large battery runs the copter so not all the 1350 mAh is needed per flight.

So a buck converter with reasonable efficiency to operate the camera from the main battery will add relatively minimal load and the slight reduction in weight will partially make up for this.

**SO** using one battery for both seems sound.

**Note that**

- A camera MAY have current peaks rather larger than its average draw - a converter must support these.
- The buck converter needs to be well behaved and NEVER output excess voltage, that your camera's days may be long on the face of the land. If you do not trust the converter 110% you may wish to add a good capacity zener (overvoltage protection) diode across Vin_camera fed by a fuse from Vout_converter so that the fuse blows if Vout is excessive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer,Do you know any good book or reading on the subject ? These camera are expensive ( been modified for the purpose of the research ) and i need to be sure i will not damage them.